# how to insert records from a aspx.vb file to a mdb datase code

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Hey there good evening can anyone tell me whats wrong with my code? I'm getting an 'operation not updateable' error like the one below

```
 Server Error in '/' Application.
 Operation must use an updateable query.

 Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current 
  webrequest. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error 
  and where it originated in the code. 

  Exception Details: System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Operation must use an
 updateable query.

  Source Error: 


      Line 20:          cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("paswords", TextBox4.Text)
      Line 21:          conn.Open()
      Line 22:          cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
      Line 23:          End Using
      Line 24:          End Using
```

My code is

```
    Imports System.Web.Security
    Imports System.Data
    Imports System.Data.OleDb
    Imports System.Configuration
    Imports System.Web.Configuration

    Partial Class Registration
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim ConnString As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|onlineregistration.mdb"
        Dim SqlString As String = "Insert Into registration (firtsname, telephone, email, paswords) Values (?,?,?,?)"
        Using conn As New OleDbConnection(ConnString)
            Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, conn)
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("firtsname", TextBox1.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("telephone", TextBox2.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("email", TextBox3.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("paswords", TextBox4.Text)
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteScalar()
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That error "must use an updateable query" is tipically thrown when the mdb file is write-only, or when there is no write permission on the file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your ASP.NET account (in most cases NETWORK SERVICE) has Read/Write access to that MDB file/folder it is stored in. Sometimes IUSR_MachineName account is required as well

You can also try adding `Mode=ReadWrite;` to your connecting string.